# Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js): (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError

Tags: angular, npm, font-awesome

i'm following Angular course on coursera
i installed font-awesome using npm install font-awesome@latest --save

then i added a new file named _variables.scss in the src folder
containing

```
$fa-font-path : '../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts';
```

and added to styles.scss file

```
@import 'variables';
@import '../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
```

despite, we have the same code, I have this error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don´t know if it can resolve your problem but I got a similar error and that worked for me.

**Partial files hierarchy in my angular project**

```
/node_modules <--useful for the app project
/projects
-/my-lib-name
--/node_modules <-- useful for my library
---/fontawesome
--/src
---/lib
----/components
-----/my-component
------my-component.component.scss
```

**my-component.component.scss [BEFORE]**

```
$fa-font-path: "../../../../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts";
```

I changed by

**my-component.component.scss [AFTER]**

```
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts";
```

And I added `node_modules` in `styleIncludePaths` in `ng-package.json` at the root of `my-lib-name`

**ng-package.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/my-lib-name",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts",
    "styleIncludePaths": ["node_modules"]
  }
}
```

Comment: For me removing the / from the url to refer fonts helped in eliminating the error.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. Just added single slash / in all URLs (/../../assets) where assets are located in the root under the src / node_modules Folder. It's working as expected as per the documentation which means it will look from the current path.

**Before**

```
$fa-font-path: "../../../../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts";
```

**After**

```
$fa-font-path: "/../../../../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the latest version of Angular (11.0.6) instead of the one used in this course (6.2.1).

I came across some version differences, to fix this one I switched the variable path in **_variables.scss** to

```
$fa-font-path : '~/node_modules/font-awesome/fonts';
```

That got me rid that error and the FontAwesome icons are being displayed now also.